# How to make pytest wait for (manual) user action?

Tags: python, pytest

We are sucessfully using pytest (Python 3) to run a test suite testing some hardware devices (electronics). 
For a subset of these tests, we need the tester to change the hardware arrangement, and afterwards change it back. 
My approach was to use a module-level fixture attached to the tests in question (which are all in a separate module), with two `input` calls:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def disconnect_component():
    input('Disconnect component, then press enter')
    yield  # At this point all the tests with this fixture are run
    input('Connect component again, then press enter')
```

When running this, I get `OSError: reading from stdin while output is captured`. I can avoid this by calling pytest with `--capture=no`, and have confirmed that my approach works, meaning I get the first query before the test subset in question, and the second one after they have run.

The big drawback is that this deactivates capturing stdin/stderr for the whole test suite, which some of the other test rely on.

I also tried to use `capsys.disabled` ([docs](http://doc.pytest.org/en/3.0.6/capture.html?highlight=capsys.disabled#accessing-captured-output-from-a-test-function)) like this

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def disconnect_component(capsys):
    with capsys.disabled():
        input('Disconnect component, then press enter')
        yield  # At this point all the tests with this fixture are run
        input('Connect component again, then press enter')
```

but when running this I get `ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'capsys' with a 'module' scoped request object, involved factories`.

Can I make pytest wait for user action in some other way than `input`? If not, can I disable capturing just for the tests using above fixture?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, I found a [hint](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/1599#issuecomment-261964636) by a pytest dev, based on which I basically do what the `capsys.disable()` function does:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def disconnect_component(pytestconfig):
    capmanager = pytestconfig.pluginmanager.getplugin('capturemanager')

    capmanager.suspend_global_capture(in_=True)
    input('Disconnect component, then press enter')
    capmanager.resume_global_capture()

    yield  # At this point all the tests with this fixture are run

    capmanager.suspend_global_capture(in_=True)
    input('Connect component again, then press enter')
    capmanager.resume_global_capture()
```

This works flawlessly as far as I can see. Don't forget the `in_=True` bit.

Edit: From pytest 3.3.0 (I think), `capmanager.suspendcapture` and `capmanager.resumecapture` were [renamed](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/commit/22f338d74d19e188a5a88a51cc722b771b07c24c) to `capmanager.suspend_global_capture` and `capmanager.resume_global_capture`, respectively.

Comment: "stdin is not needed in automatic testing" -> At work I have to use some executables  from the stoneage (written in Fortran 77). I cant rewrite them cause I haven't the sources. So I wrote some pythoncode using Popen to glue these old exes to a toolchain. This old executables rely heavely on user input, which is almost "hit enter to continue"). Your answer gives me the opertunity to use pipe in input via subprocess.communicate and using pytest for testing the whole toolchain :)

Comment: great to hear that it's useful! Python as a glue language rocks! :-D

Answer (score 7):

As of pytest 5, as a fixture, you can use this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def suspend_capture(pytestconfig):
    class suspend_guard:
        def __init__(self):
            self.capmanager = pytestconfig.pluginmanager.getplugin('capturemanager')
        def __enter__(self):
            self.capmanager.suspend_global_capture(in_=True)
        def __exit__(self, _1, _2, _3):
            self.capmanager.resume_global_capture()

    yield suspend_guard()
```

Example usage:

```
def test_input(suspend_capture):
    with suspend_capture:
        input("hello")
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's worth noting that above solution doesn't have to be in a fixture. I've made a helper function for that:

```
import pytest

def ask_user_input(msg=''):
    """ Asks user to check something manually and answer a question
    """
    notification = "\n\n???\tANSWER NEEDED\t???\n\n{}".format(msg)

    # suspend input capture by py.test so user input can be recorded here
    capture_manager = pytest.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('capturemanager')
    capture_manager.suspendcapture(in_=True)

    answer = raw_input(notification)

    # resume capture after question have been asked
    capture_manager.resumecapture()

    logging.debug("Answer: {}".format(answer))
    return answer
```

Comment: Yeah that could be useful for some. In our case, though, we need that in a fixture:  *For a subset of these tests, we need the tester to change the hardware arrangement, and afterwards change it back*

Answer (score 3):

For future reference, if you need to use `input` with `pytest`. You can do this in any part of your pytest, `setup_class`, `test_...`, `teardown_method`, etc. This is for `pytest > 3.3.x`

```
import pytest

capture_manager = pytest.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('capturemanager')
capture_manager.suspend_global_capture(in_=True)
answer = input('My reference text here')
capture_manager.resume_global_capture()
```

Comment: Thanks. The other answers didn't work for me as they seem to be using previous version of Python/pytest.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions that use the global `pytest.config` object no longer work. For my use case, using `--capture=sys` together with a custom `input()` that uses `stdin` and `stdout` directly works well.

```py
def fd_input(prompt):
    with os.fdopen(os.dup(1), "w") as stdout:
        stdout.write("\n{}? ".format(prompt))

    with os.fdopen(os.dup(2), "r") as stdin:
        return stdin.readline()
```